# Paste clipboard data on button press

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard

`window.addEventListener("paste", pasteHandler);//detects paste event and calls function`

`function pasteHandler(e) {//code here}`

I have another button, which needs to call the same pasteHandler function . I could think of the following, which is not working

```
 $('#Button1').bind("click", pasteHandler);
```

The pastehandler function copies the clipboard data into a div. help required.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like you have it figured out. What's the question?

Comment: @JJ56 the problem is that on pressing Button1 , the pasteHandler(e) event should be called. (which at this point is being called on Ctl+V). Even if the pasteHandler is called via the $.trigger("paste"), the event passed in pasteHandler(e) remains empty.

Answer (score 0):

It may work:

```
$('#Button1').bind("click", function() {
   $.trigger("paste");
});
```

EDIT:
try this:

```
$('#Button1').bind("click", function(e) {
   pasteHandler(e);
});
```

Comment: the pasteHandler function needs an event to be passed as its argument.